# How to highlight search results in HTML input text using PHP?

Tags: php, html, regex, highlight

I have some input HTML and I need to highlight some words in it.
I saw many advices how to do it and now I use preg_replace.

```php
 $output = preg_replace("/\w*?" . preg_quote($keyword) . "\w*/i",
        "<span class=\"entity_hilight\">$0</span>", $input);
```

It works good at all, but if the input HTML does not contain a keyword in some of attributes of tags.

For example if I need to highlight keyword "Hawaii", this HTML code will be broken after applying the code above:

```html
Hawaii is on of the best places for fun and recreation. Welcome to <a href="http://example.com/Hawaii">Hawaii hotels</a>
```

Because the code will replace Hawaii not only in the `<a>` tag, but in the `href` attribute too.

So how to avoid breaking HTML code with highlighting? Please note that I need to highlight words inside and outside HTML tags both, also it should work properly with nested tags. Tags as well as attributes can have any, even custom names, so I can't explicitly define any list of possible tag and attribute names. Also sometimes keyword can match not only with attribute value, but with attribute name or tag name (for example if I would need higlight keyword "strong" or "article" or "class").

Comment: E.g. https://regex101.com/r/Dcjrw3/1. Or https://regex101.com/r/Dcjrw3/2

Comment: This is a case for... __Zalgo man__! Ehm, I mean, do I really need to link there.